# AngularJS directive and pulling data from a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am trying to figure out the correct way to pull data into my directive from a service. For some reason my $watch statement isn't triggered when the data is loaded.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            scope.loadtext = testService.getJSON();

            scope.$watch(scope.loadtext, function(newValue, oldValue){

                if (newValue !== oldValue){
                    alert("watch working");
                    element.addClass("red");
                    element.html(newValue.ok);
                }
            });


        }
```

Simple JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jamesamuir/m85Ka/1/

However, I am not sure if I am approaching this the right way. I have tried to dig into the documentation for Directives but it doesn't seem to be providing much insight into solving this.

Comment: Try `scope.$watch('loadtext',function(){....});`

Comment: Tim, thanks for the quick response. I updated the link with the correct JSFiddle where I tried your suggestion. It did not appear to work. The bigger question is if I am even doing this the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final goal is but I think you're not using the right approach.
Anyway I updated the jsfiddle and kept the $watch though it's not needed.

The problem is here:

```
this.getJSON = function() {
    $http.get('http://ricardohbin.com/cors/testcors.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                 alert(data);
                return data;
            });
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(status + " | bad");
        });
}
```

Your `return data` is not associated to `getJSON` but to the `$rootScope.$apply` callback in this code. You cannot `return` in this situation, instead use a callback as the data will be loaded asynchronously like that:

```
testService.getJSON(function(data) {
    scope.loadtext = data;
});
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.loadtext = testService.getJSON();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m85Ka/10/

Answer (score 3):

While Tim Withers suggestion will work for your problem, the correct way to load data is either from the view's controller function or in the directive's own controller.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jamesamuir/m85Ka/2/ with both of your suggestions but I still cannot get it to work. It seems that there should be an easier way to load data from a service than this?