# Preloading data in a Directive using promises in a service using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service

I hope someone can help me.  I have not been able to figure this one out.

I wrote a directive (see below) to dump a pre-written ul-list on a page based on html data that I retrieved async from a database server.  Both the Directive and The Service work.

I assumed that the "then" in "MenuService.getMenuData().then" would force a wait until the data arrived to the directive but some how the directive completes and shows the '3empty' message before the data arrived, which indicates that the directive completed earlier. I know I could put a timeout delay but that is not good. Do you have a suggestion as to what could the problem be?
The other technique I used was to put a ng-show="dataarrived" and set the dataarrived to true only when the promised completed.  But same issue.

The purpose of this directive is to retrieve the Nav menu list from the serve and display it on the index.html but It does Not matter if I put this code in a controller or in a service or directive I get the same result. It shows nothing.  It is particular to displaying it in the index.html before any other view is displayed.

Here is my directive if it make sense.

TBApp.directive('tbnavMenu', function ($compile, MenuService) {
    var tbTemplate = '3empty';

```
MenuService.getMenuData().then(function (val) {
    tbTemplate = val;
});
var getTemplate = function () {
    return tbTemplate;
}

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(tbTemplate).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}

return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    link: linker,
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {

        $scope.selectedNavMenu = GlobalService.appData.currentNavMenu;
        $scope.menuClicked = function ($event, menuClicked) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $scope.selectedNavMenu = menuClicked;
            $scope.tbnavMenuHander({ navMenuChanged: menuClicked });
        };
        $scope.isSelected = function (menuClicked) {
            return $scope.selectedNavMenu === menuClicked;
        }
    },
    scope: {
        tbnavMenuHander: '&'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I could be incredibly wrong but if your service is returning an $http object at the getMenuData method then these lines:

```
MenuService.getMenuData().then(function (val) {
    tbTemplate = val;
});
```

should change to either:

```
MenuService.getMenuData().then(function (val) {
    tbTemplate = val.data;
});
```

or

```
MenuService.getMenuData().success(function (val) {
    tbTemplate = val;
});
```

My personal recomendation is to use the .then option as it enables the concatenation of more promises.

Comment: Thanks @HeberLZ for your response.  Silly of me, I should have pointed that out. val is already a valdata, the deferred portion does it for me.  My problem is that when the data arrives, it arrives too late and the directive renders the '3empty' rather than the html tags i retrieve from the server.  If I were to use the save directive in a subsequent view (page), the data retrieve from the server renders OK. It is mind-boggling

Comment: I found the solution. I found it in a solution provided by Seb Fanals, here is the link.  Note, in my case, I did need the $watch for the linker to populate the menu list again.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590120/angularjs-directive-and-pulling-data-from-a-service?rq=1